# Python 3 equivalent of HTMLParseError?

Tags: python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I just wanted to know if there is any Python 3 equivalent of the `HTMLParseError` as in Python 2. `HTMLParseError` seems to have been deprecated from Python 3.3 onward and removed in Python 3.5.

Is there any way to catch the `HTMLParseError` in Python versions > 3.5?

Following is a traceback I receive:

```
  File "/opt/Projects/WAFToast/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    HTMLParseError = html.parser.HTMLParseError
AttributeError: module 'html.parser' has no attribute 'HTMLParseError'
```

Doing some Googling around, I [found](https://github.com/stephenmcd/mezzanine/issues/1413) the same issue being fixed with a patch as below which imho is not a wholesome solution:

```
try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParseError
except ImportError:  # Python 3.5+
    class HTMLParseError(Exception):
        pass
```

It would be really great if someone could point out the necessary I am missing. =)

Comment: `HTMLParseError` was deprecated because it would no longer be raised. The patch *is* a valid solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParseError) say:

> Deprecated since version 3.3, will be removed in version 3.5: This exception has been deprecated because it’s **never raised by the parser (when the default non-strict mode is used)**.

It was removed because nothing raised it unless the (presumably) little used strict mode is used, so a question must be asked: "are you using the strict mode?"

If you are not, you can safely remove the import and the code that catches it.

If you are, check what exception is raised instead (if at all), and import it instead.

If you use strict mode and have to support both versions of Python, you can do something along the lines of

```
try:
    from html.parser import HTMLParseError as ParseError
except ImportError:  # Python 3.5+
    from html.parser import NewTypeOfFancyException as ParseError
```

then use `except ParseError` where applicable.

Comment: I'm not using the strict mode, nor ever was I. However, I am using BeautifulSoup (as the tags on this question indicate), and was previously using it with Py2. I know this error occurred in Py2 (and suggested to install another parser).
BS makes the decision to use strict mode or not for us. So this isn't even an answer to the question. Does BS use strict mode? How do you tell if it uses strict mode? Does the fact it could throw this in Py2 mean it uses strict mode? What is NewTypeOfFancyException, or what happens in strict mode? Or has strict mode also been removed?

Comment: @DimeCadmium As of June 2023, Python 2 is EOL'ed for about 3 and a half years by now. Python 3.4 is EOL'ed for even longer. I can't see why this would still be a problem.

Comment: as of Jan 2020, this was not an answer to the question. It still is not.

Comment: @DimeCadmium Then feel free posting your own answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not know the actual answer. That's why I was looking on StackOverflow. Also unfortunately, this non-answer is all that's to be found.